# Wireless connection has good signal but rarely manages to connect

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a wireless 802.g adsl modem-router (SAGEM F@st 3464).

The connection signal is great (4-5 lines according to windows) however
when you try to connect it just says that there is an error (no specific info).

Very rarely it actually manages to connect, it stays on for a few mins or less (30 seconds?) and then disconnects.

I tried many different approaches:

- tried different wlan adapters
- used static ip
- tried no encryption/wep/wpa
- made sure no mac filtering was enabled
- changed the ssid channel (1, 2, 10)
- disabled ssid broadcast (you have to type the name of the ap yourself)
- ran windows in safe mode

One thing I noticed is that the connection bandwidth varies. On the few occasions I managed to connect I tested the speed. The readings varied from 3 mbs down to 7 mbs.

I have no idea what the problem is. Someone who might have an idea please help me.

Comment: How close is the PC to the WIFI?

Comment: Hmm one floor? this equals maybe 4m. with walls in between.

Answer (score 1):

if your computer is a notebook, 1 floor should work but if it's a desktop, I could't manage to have a decent connection on 1 floor difference with usb adapters or isa cards on 4 different desktops and 4 different adapters but notebooks work very well connecting to the same wi-fi router at longer distances... As I had desktops on both floors I installed the router in the stairs and this way it worked (not very stable but usable) for some time but now I use a cable! ;)

Try to bring the router and computer to the same floor and see if you can connect better to test if the distance (or geometry) is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Some troubleshooting steps you may or may not have tried:

- Resetting the router to factory
  defaults and reconfiguring.
- Updating the router firmware.
- Moving the router & pc to eliminate
  interference.
- Trying a different router.